# Customize ui:debug

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

In order to analyze the component tree a better way, I use `<ui:debug/>`.
Now I would like to customize this debug-window in order to optimize analyzing.

---

### Prerequisites

I add following JavaScript-code using the JavaScript-console in Chrome.

```
(function () {
    var newscript = document.createElement('script');
    newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newscript.async = true;
    newscript.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(newscript);
})();
```

for adding jQuery to the debug-window and

```
hideAll = function () {
    $('dd').addClass('hidden').removeClass('visible')
};
showAll = function () {
    $('dd').addClass('visible')
};
hideAll();
$('<span class="toggle toggleButton">toggle</span>').insertBefore('dl:has(dd)');
$('#tree').find('> code').prepend('<span class="toggleButton" onclick="showAll()">showAll</span>').prepend('<span class="toggleButton" onclick="hideAll()">hideAll</span>');

$('<style type="text/css">.hidden {display: none;}.visible {display: block;}.toggleButton{padding-left: 30px;}</style>').appendTo($('head'));
$('.toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).next().children().toggleClass('visible');
}).each(function () {
    $(this).append(' (' + $(this).next().find('dd').length + ' children)')
});
```

for counting the components and adding some buttons to toggle the component-children.

---

### Question

Now I wonder, if I could modify the `ui:debug`-component a cleaner way. My problems:

- I can't overload the renderer of ui:debug with following xml-code in the `faces-config.xml`. I also cannot inherit from `com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.UIDebug` because it's final and it would be implementation-dependend anyway.

  ```
  <render-kit>
      <renderer>
          <component-family>facelets</component-family>
          <renderer-type>facelets.ui.Debug</renderer-type>
          <renderer-class>com.my.CustomDebug</renderer-class>
      </renderer>
  </render-kit>
  ```
- I can't create a custom tag and reuse `UIDebug` because `facesContext.getResponseWriter()` of function `encodeBegin` returns null at this moment
- I cannot listen to `preRenderView`-Event because this event is not invoked when opening the debug-window. But I think, listening to some event would be promising.

Do you have some ideas for this?

Comment: Small remark (not a solution): Your jquery code is already implementation dependend afaics. Mojarra renders the debug differently

Comment: Thank you for the remark. I currently use Mojarra, but I will provide a implementation independend solution after I know how to hook into ;)